# CSS background black behind high position footer

Tags: css

I have a set height footer div that fills the bottom of the screen, 100px wide, with a black background it sits over a body Back ground image. There are a few pages with not a lot of content. The footer rises up the page and because it has a fixed height, under the footer you see the body BG image. How would I go about using CSS to make sure that the whole screen below the raised footer is black, without having to extend the set height of the footer div?

Comment: code in too many files.. heres a link:
http://projects.snowshtechnologies.com/golden_dragon/profiles/

Answer (score 0):

You can give "min-height" to the pages that .So, although content is little, the footer will be same.Since content area has "min-height"

You can have a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) for "min-height"

And here is sample code;

```
.content {
   min-height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: thats gonna need some JS to identify screen res.... there must be a method to fill to the bottom of the screen. have been trying :after

Answer (score 0):

There are some published solutions to this.  The core of them all seems to be applying minimum heights (including some hacks for earlier versions of IE) to a block-level element that wraps all non-footer content and has a padding equal to the footer's height.  The footer then has its height and negative top margin set explicitly (to the same value as the wrapper's bottom-padding.

Code example from [the CSS Sticky Footer solution](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!--[if !IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```

Comment: im not looking to make the footer sticky, instead we are happy for it to move up to the high position, but the background below the footer needs to be filled black.